# Expo DocumentPicker MIME filter isn't working with JSON

Tags: android, json, react-native, mime-types, expo

I'm using React Native (v 0.47.2) and Expo (v20.0.0) for Android app development. I need to make a document picker whick can only select JSON files.

So, my code is:

`Expo.DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({type: 'application/json'})`

But all `.json` files are disabled with this MIME filter (tested on Android 7.1.1). What I'm doing wrong if everything works with `type: */*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, Android simple doesn't know JSON MIME type. The only solution is using another files extension from [this list](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java).